# jquery mobile page swipe fires only once

Tags: jquery-mobile

Absolute newcomer to jQuery mobile.
I'm trying to create a 'mock up' e-magazine using jquery mobile and page swipe to move between the pages.

The initial 'swipe' works but after that nothing. Can't go forward or back. I've been going over the code but can't see what I'm missing. You can see the [test site here](http://mofilm.holdenandsons.com).

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're getting multiplied `swipe` events on each `pageinit`. You can either delegate `swipe` events once, or bind them to each page individually during `pagecreate` (`pageinit`). Edit: moving `swipe` bindings outside `pageinit` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Omar – as I said, I'm a complete newby. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I just noticed that you're using a _single page model_, but it isn't an issue here. Anyway, move `swipe` binding outside `pageinit` and try again.